# extended SharePoint server 2010 lists have problem with columns that have customized forms for their data gathering with InfoPath 2010

Tags: 2010, infopath, upgrade, list-form

our server is upgraded from 2007 and we have problems there that force us to decide to move sites to the new 2010 web application.

after that we have problem with excel services that solutions and suggestion in the internet can not solve it. we decide to extend that and after that we have new problem:

detail :

1. lists that have form for data gathering and customized by info path broke their links to their list columns
2. it seems the string type columns are good work but number values broken.

what is your solution?

Comment: The pre-history you are describing is not crystal clear. Details might be beneficial for resolution: was it an in-place upgrade or DB-attach? What was the issue with Excel Services? What do you mean by "we decide to extend that and after that..."?

Comment: Have you tried editing the form template, remapping the fields and re-publishing the form template?